# "a chance to meet" vs "a chance that we meet"

Tags: word-usage, sentence-choice, sentence-usage

> - Please let me know if there is a chance *that we meet* somewhere in or outside Chicago.
> - Please let me know if there is a chance *to meet* somewhere in or outside Chicago.

Which one between these two sentences is correct?

**Context:** Depending on the availability of a friend, I want him to let me know if there is a chance that we can meet (or to meet) somewhere. The complete sentence is: "Depending on how far you live from Chicago and your availability, and knowing that I won't be available on the 4th of December, please let me know if there is a chance to meet somewhere in or outside Chicago".

Comment: a chance **for us** to meet. would be the usual expression here.

Answer (score 1):

The second option reads like you're asking a general, open-ended question about possibility of meeting. It's almost like a question about statistics, given your context.

The first option reads like you're trying to make an appointment/arrangement to meet, which seems to fit your context better. So, the first sentence is correct, in this context.

Comment: The first example is not correct because it's missing the word "could".

Comment: The second sentence sounds fine to me. Since it is slightly shorter, I would prefer it.

Comment: I disagree, I'd actually say the opposite. "A chance that we meet" implies they'd run into each other randomly on the street; "a chance to meet" suggests OP wants to schedule a meeting.

Answer (score 0):

> Please let me know if there is a chance that we meet somewhere in or outside Chicago.

To me, this is asking about the probability of randomly encountering them in public.

> I don't know Barack Obama, but he and I will both be in Cook County next week so there's a chance that we meet somewhere in or outside Chicago.

---

> Please let me know if there is a chance to meet somewhere in or outside Chicago.

This is closer to what you're looking for, but I'd suggest "if you have a chance…"

> Please let me know if you have a chance to meet up somewhere in or outside Chicago.

If you actually know them and have gotten together in the past, you may want to be a bit more direct

> Hey Barack, I'll be near Chicago next week. Are you free to meet up some time then?